# Unable to use bucket map join in hive 0.12

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

I was trying out some hive optimization features and encountered such problem:
I cannot use bucket map join in hive 0.12. After all the setting I tried below, **only one hashtable** file is generated and the join turn out to be just **map join**.

---

I have two tables both in rcfile format and both bucktized into 10 bucket, they are created and populated as follows(Origin data was generated from TPC-H):

```
hive> create table lsm (l_orderkey int, l_partkey int, l_suppkey int, l_linenumber int, l_quantity double, l_extendedprice double, l_discount double, l_tax double, l_returnflag string, l_linestatus string, l_shipdate string, l_commitdate string, l_receiptdate string, l_shipstruct string, l_shipmode string, l_comment string) clustered by (l_orderkey) into 10 buckets stored as rcfile;
hive> create table osm (o_orderkey int, o_custkey int) clustered by (o_orderkey) into 10 buckets stored as rcfile;
hive> set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
hive> insert overwrite table lsm select * from orili;
hive> insert overwrite table osm select o_orderkey, o_custkey from orior;
```

And I can query both table’s data normally, and lsm is 790MB, osm is 11MB, both 10 bucket files, then I want to try bucket map join:

```
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true; 
hive> set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
hive> set hive.enforce.bucketmapjoin=true;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=1000000000000000;
hive> set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat;
```

and my query is as follows:

```
hive> select /*+ Mapjoin(osm) */ osm.o_orderkey, lsm.* from osm join lsm on osm.o_orderkey = lsm.l_orderkey;
```

This query only generate 1 hashtable of osm and fall back to a map join, I was really confused about it. Do I have all the hint set to enable the bucket map join feature, or are there any problems in my query ?

Comment: /*+ Mapjoin(osm) */ is a query hint that instructs Hive to do a map join with osm as the hash table. These sorts of hints are not needed since Hive 11. Remove that and see what happens. Given osm is only 11MB, a mapjoin may be faster than a bucket join for this data.

Comment: @CarterShanklin, thanks for your reply. I tried to not give MAPJOIN hint, still just 1 hashtable file generated. I know in my situation, 11M's table is small enough to just use map join, I just want to try bucket map join out, sadly, it seems doesn't work... Have you used bucket map join before & what's your configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Version:** 
Set `hive> set hive.ignore.mapjoin.hint=false;`
will make Bucket Map Join work as Expected. Which means I would get the 10 small tables's bucket files build as hash table and do hash join with its corresponding big file's buckets.

**A longer Version:** 
I dive into the hive 0.12 code and find `hive.ignore.mapjoin.hint` in `HiveConf.java` and it was set to `true` by default, which means the `/*+ MAPJOIN */` hint is ignored deliberately. Since there are 2 phase of Optimization in hive, **logical optimization** and **physical optimization**, both are **rule based** optimizations.

- Logical Optimization 
   In the logical optimization, mapjoin optimization was followed by bucketmapjoin optimization, bucketmapjoin optimization take the MapJoin operator tree as input and convert it into BucketMapJoin, so a hinted query would be first transformed into a mapjoin and then a bucketmapjoin. Therefore, hint disabled logical optimisation would do nothing join optimisation on the join tree.
- Physical Optimization 
  In the physical optimisation, the `hive.auto.convert.join` was tested and `MapJoinResolver` was used and just convert a reduce join into a MapJoin. No further BucketMapJoin Optimization rules in this phase. That's why I just get Mapjoin in my question.